# Rails says secret_key_base is missing but it's in my credentials file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was in the process of removing my cleartext passwords from `config/database.yml` and so I used `EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit` to move all the information there instead.

At the top of this, I can see that `secret_key_base` is already set. So I'm not quite sure why I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the following command: `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production`

```
# bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production                                                                                                                         6:24AM/09.26
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit
```

Just to give a little output of what I see at the top of the file when I use that command to edit the credentials:

```
# aws:
#   access_key_id: 123
#   secret_access_key: 345

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.

default: &default
  host: 172.17.0.1
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  username: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  password: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]

test:
  <<: *default
  database: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  username: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  password: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]

production:
  <<: *default
  database: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  username: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  password: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
  secret_key_base: [obfuscated for stackoverflow]
```

At first, `secret_key_base` was the first line in this file, but that still didn't work so I moved it down to under production.

I'm totally confused on how this is all supposed to work. From what I understand, my `config/database.yml` file is supposed to call the data from the rails encrypted file, is that correct? This is how my database.yml file looks:

```
default: &default
  host: 172.17.0.1
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:database]
  username: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:username]
  password: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:password]

test:
  <<: *default
  database: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:database]
  username: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:username]
  password: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:password]

production:
  <<: *default
  database: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:database]
  username: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:username]
  password: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:password]
  secret_key_base: Rails.application.credentails[Rails.env.to_sym][:secret_key_base]
```

but I know something is wrong here, just not sure what...

How do I fix this issue? I'm using Rails 5.2.3 and trying to migrate from using `database.yml` and use the new method of storing credentials instead.

Comment: You dont need `secret_key_base ` inside `secret_key_base `. Try putting in `sercrets.yml`

Comment: @SahilGrover I thought the new way of storing credentials eliminated the need for `secrets.yml`. Is that not true? https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

Comment: what rails version are you on ?

Comment: Rails 5.2.3. I'm trying to go away from using config/database.yml and use the new way of storing credentials to get my rails app production ready.

Comment: I am also using rails '~> 5.1.4', and using secrets.yml with it,  works perfectly fine.

Comment: I believe Rails 5.2 is trying to replace the need for `secrets.yml` according to that article. Just trying to apply best practices to the rails app before making it available to the public.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782241/separate-secret-key-base-in-rails-5-2 check this one

Comment: That did the trick for me. Thanks! I guess you still need `secrets.yml` even though Rails 5.2 is supposed to be getting rid of it, which makes no sense to me. It seems like it's still a requirement and doesn't read it from the encrypted credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 5.2 the secrets are handles with an encrypted file. The important thing is: There is no environment scope to the secret_key_base. Enter your secret_key_base right on top of that file in lower case letters.

(edit the file from your rails root like e.g. so:
`EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit)`